# Рамка (обводка) вокруг фрагмента

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-layout

На первом скриншоте - то что я вижу в android studio. На втором - то что появляется при запуске программы. Текст находится в `layout`-е фрагмента.
Как избавиться от белой рамки как на втором скрине? `Layout` имеет свойства `match_parent`. Заранее спасибо.
[image: Это я вижу при проектировании хмл разметки]
[image: Это получается при запуске программы на устройстве]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Никогда не пользуйтесь предпросмоторщиком, встроенным в `IDE` - он полон багов и править их, скорее всего, никогда не будут, ибо им никто не пользуется, ибо он не нужен.
2. Отступы, кои вы видите, где-то у вас в разметке. Ищите в коде/разметке активити/фрагмента `margin` и/или `padding`. Уберите их и отступы пропадут.

Comment: Юрий, Вы меня выручаете раз за разом, спасибо огромное. Если не пользоваться стоковым предпросмоторщиком, тогда с помощью чего следует моделировать внешний вид приложения?

Comment: Пожалуйста) Ну... Просто представляете в голове как оно должно выглядеть и описываете на языке xml... А в живую поглядеть можно на девайсе/эмуляторе. Иначе-вот такие проблемы. Сам я начинал в Eclipse писать и там предпросмоторщик вообще не работал, так что без него вполне можно (и нужно) обойтись)

Comment: Не то, чтобы визуальный редактор был полон именно багов .. отрендерить корректно в не родной среде выполнения не такая простая задача, как может показаться, есть множество нюансов, которые неполноценному эмулятору очень трудно воспроизвести.

Comment: @pavlofff, я примерно это и имел в виду) Чем сложнее проект, тем больше данных надо учитывать (ресурсы под разные экраны, локали; что-то во фрагментах, что-то в активити, что-то в стилях приложения, что-то в стилях активити, что-то в стиле вьюхи etc). В итоге всё не учесть.

Comment: Я согласен, что Prewiew очень не стабильный и много факторов надо учитывать, прописывать в tools "намекать"  как ему реагировать и тд. Баги есть, тоже факт - никто не отрицает, но говорить мол "он не нужен", как-то перебор. Пускай будет)) а люди со временем поймут, использовать или нет.  Плохой момент, что люди начинают ему доверять и думают, что как он кажет так и будет, но это далеко не так - отсюда траблы

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, всё же буду стоять на том, что он не нужен в связи с тем, что слишком многое надо учитывать при работе с ним - проще на устройстве/эмуляторе запустить. Тот же гамбургер же, вообще (насколько я знаю), можно только программно задать. Т.е. надо ещё и компилятор заюзать. Ну и с тёмной/светлой темой (до вчерашнего обновления) в просмоторщике без компилятора не обойтись, ибо тема в рантайме задаётся, а не из ресурсов как теперь можно.

Comment: Если идет верстка Activity, абсолютно согласен, если она тяжелая особенно, там вообще может ничего не отображаться. Я сам использую только железо и это не подводит. 
А если к примеру вы в drawable работаете с svg например, очень даже полезен ибо от изменения пару точек нет смысла загружать проект, а там он вполне хорошо работает. Ну это как пример. В целом это лишенные смысла комменты, тк нравится или нет, поэтому вам за ответ +1.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, с `SVG` не работал, судить не возьмусь, но так да - размер там текста, отступы в разметке к-л элемента разметки списка посмотреть можно, да... Но аккуратно) И, кстати, во второй студии, вроде, обещали изменения на девайсе отображать без пересборки проекта - может быть оно будет нормально работать и предпросмоторщик более вообще не понадобится) Ну а комменты не совсем бесполезны - всё ж мы агрументированно тут, вроде, общаемся)